# To find matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

$T \colon {\mathbb R}^2$ maps into ${\mathbb R}^3$.

$T(1,1)=(0,0,1)$ and $T(1,2)=(0,1,1)$

Find the associated matrix to the standard bases.

Well I really know how to find matrix of a LT, e.g., I can find the matrix of say $T(x,y)=(4x-2y,2x+y)$ with given basis. But what does the term standard bases mean? And this one looks a bit different. How to find $T (x,y)$?

Comment: @Magdiragdag yeah

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since T(1,1)=(0,0,1) and T(1,2)=(0,1,1) are given we try to find T(1,0) and T(0,1) using the given information and the linearity of T. Notice that (1,0) = 2(1,1)-(1,2) and (0,1) = -(1,1) + (1,2) therefore T(1,0) = 2T(1,1)-T(1,2) = (0,-1,1) and T(0,1) = -T(1,1)+T(1,2) = (0,1,0). Thus the required matrix is A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ -1 & 1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}

Comment: Thanks for ur time.

Answer (score 0):

The standard basis of ${\mathbb R}^2$ is $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ and, similarly, the standard basis of ${\mathbb R}^3$ is $\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$.

You're given a linear transformation $T \colon {\mathbb R}^2 \to {\mathbb R}^3$ by $T(1,1) = (0,0,1)$ and $T(1,2)$. Because $\{(1,1), (1,2)\}$ is a basis of ${\mathbb R}^2$, this fully determines $T$.

Finding the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard bases boils down to figuring out what $T(1,0)$ and $T(0,1)$ are. Now $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ can be written as linear combinations of $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$; using the fact that $T$ is linear and knowing the values of $T$ at $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$ will give you $T(1,0)$ and $T(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

In the basis $v_1=(1,1)$ and $v_2=(1,2)$ the matrix from this basis to the canonical is given by

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\\1&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now you can plug the change of basis to find the marix in the canonical basis.

To do this note that the following matrix M which has $v_i$ as column vectors

$$M=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

is the matrix that convert vectors from the $v_i$ basis to the canonical:

$$w=Mv$$

thus its invers convert vectors from the canonical to the $v_i$ basis:

$$v=M^{-1}w$$

then, since the transfomation from the v_i basis to the canonical is expressed by

$$u=Av$$

the transfomation in the canonical basis is given by

$$u=AM^{-1}w$$